# My property only has a get, but I want that value to change everytime I call it

Tags: c#, properties, interface

I am struggling with the this for a few hours now. I only want to use a get in my property. When I call a function, it gets a number from that property(10) and should substract 1 from the 10, which makes 9. But I have no idea how to save this 9, and do it minus 1 everytime, so the next time I call it, it becomes 8. I Hope this is clear enough.

main.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;



namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            do
            {
                Zwakmonster zwakmonster = new Zwakmonster();
                Sterkmonster sterkmonster = new Sterkmonster();
                List<IMonster> monster = new List<IMonster>();
                string lijn;
                string test = "exit";
                string nieuwelijn;
                string zwak = "zwakmonster";
                string sterk = "sterkmonster";
                string groen = "groen";
                string geel = "geel";


                Sterkmonster henk = new Sterkmonster();
                henk.Naam = sterk;
                henk.Kleur = groen;
                Zwakmonster piet = new Zwakmonster();
                piet.Kleur = geel;
                piet.Naam = zwak;

                Console.WriteLine("Schrijf zwakmonster_iemand of sterkmonster_iemand");


                lijn = Console.ReadLine();

                if (lijn == test)
                {
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }

                else if (lijn.StartsWith("hit"))
                {
                    if (lijn.StartsWith("hit "))
                    {


                        nieuwelijn = lijn.Remove(0, 4);


                        if (nieuwelijn == sterk)
                        {

                            henk.Hit();
                            Console.WriteLine(sterkmonster);

                        }
                        else if (nieuwelijn == zwak)
                        {

                            piet.Hit();

                            Console.WriteLine(zwakmonster);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("iets ging er fout");
                        }


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Ben je misschien een spatie vergeten na ''hit''?\n");

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Verkeerd commando ingevoerd\n");

                }

            } while (1 == 1);
        }
    }
}
```

IMonster.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    interface IMonster
    {






        string Naam
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        string Kleur
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        int Levens
        {
            get;
        }

       void Hit();



    }
}
```

zwakmonster.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Zwakmonster : IMonster
    {
        private string mijnNaam;
        private string mijnKleur;
        private int mijnLevens = 10;
        private int nieuwelevens;




        public string Naam
        {
            get { return mijnNaam; }
            set { mijnNaam = value; }
        }

        public string Kleur
        {
            get { return mijnKleur; }
            set { mijnKleur = value; }
        }

        public int Levens
        {
            get { return mijnLevens; }
        }


        public void Hit()
        {
            mijnLevens = mijnLevens - 1;
            nieuwelevens = mijnLevens;
            Console.WriteLine(nieuwelevens);
        }

        }
}
```

Comment: My bad, I kept making a new monster when I wrote the line "hit zwakmonster_ name" in the cmd. So I kept making new monsters and didn't save the made one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allan Elder already gave the right answer, to make things less complicated i would use only one var for your lives count

```
class Zwakmonster : IMonster
{
    private string mijnNaam;
    private string mijnKleur;
    private int lives = 10;

    public string Naam
    {
        get { return mijnNaam; }
        set { mijnNaam = value; }
    }

    public string Kleur
    {
        get { return mijnKleur; }
        set { mijnKleur = value; }
    }

    public int Levens
    {
        get { return lives; }
    }

    public void Hit()
    {
        lives = lives - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: But when I call the hit(); again I want it to be 8, and night 7 etc

Comment: Since the value is stored in "lives" it will decrement with each hit. Did you try this code? Do you maybe have other methods accessing the value?
Update: look at Allans comment, he found your problem, you are creating a new monster in each loop.

Comment: I already got the awnser, I always created a new monster when I wrote "hit zwakmonster_name" It kept making a new zwakmonster_name, which was set to 10, and when I write again "hit zwakmonster_name" it makes a new one with 10lives

Comment: I edited my quesion, When you run this, and type "hit zwakmonster" it has to go to 19, when you type it again it has to go to 18 etc

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
    public void Hit()
    {
        newlife = mijnLevens - 1;
    }
```

to this

```
    public void Hit()
    {
        mijnLevens = mijnLevens - 1;
        newlife = mijnLevens;
    }
```

this will make sure mijnLevens is decremented. Currently, mijnLevens is always 10.

Change this:

```
        do
        {
            Zwakmonster zwakmonster = new Zwakmonster();
```

To this

```
        Zwakmonster zwakmonster = new Zwakmonster();
        do
        {
```

So that you don't create a new object for every iteration.

Comment: It actually doenst work, when I call hit again it just goes to 9 again and again, instead of 8. So that when you type "hit zwakmonster_name" again and again in the console line, it goes to 9, then 8, then 7 etc

Comment: Its tough to understand as it's not in English; but move your         Zwakmonster zwakmonster = new Zwakmonster(); to be above the do statememnt; you're currently creating a new instance every time, so the mijnLevens is being set back to 0.

Comment: I already got the awnser, I always created a new monster when I wrote "hit zwakmonster_name" It kept making a new zwakmonster_name, which was set to 10, and when I write again "hit zwakmonster_name" it makes a new one with 10lives

Comment: I edited my quesion, When you run this, and type "hit zwakmonster" it has to go to 19, when you type it again it has to go to 18 etc

Answer (score 0):

mijnLevens will always have the value 10.
You need to assign the reduced value back to mijnLevens

Comment: I edited my quesion, When you run this, and type "hit zwakmonster" it has to go to 19, when you type it again it has to go to 18 etc